# setlocal(LC_ALL,"Rus"); переводит некорректно

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проблема показана на скрине, половина переводиться на русский, другая нет, куда только не пробовал вставлять setlocal(LC_ALL,"Rus"); , все равно такая проблема.

````
#include <locale>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");


    const int MAX_LENGTH = 80;

    char sentence[MAX_LENGTH];
    cout << "Введите предложение (не более 80 символов):\n";
    cin.getline(sentence, MAX_LENGTH);
    // Находим первое слово
    int firstWordEnd = 0;
    while (sentence[firstWordEnd] != ' ' && sentence[firstWordEnd] != '\0') 
    {

        firstWordEnd++;
    }

    char lastLetter = sentence[firstWordEnd - 1];
    cout << "Слова, которые заканчиваются на ту же букву, что и первое слово:\n";
    int wordCount = 0;
    int spaceCount = 0;
    bool isFirstWord = true;
    for (int i = -1; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) 
    {

        if (sentence[i] != ' ') {
            if (isFirstWord) {
                isFirstWord = false;
                continue;  // Пропускаем первое слово
            }
            bool isLastLetter = false;
            int j = i;
            while (sentence[j] != ' ' && sentence[j] != '\0') 
            {
                j++;
            }
            if (sentence[j - 1] == lastLetter) {
                int wordStart = i;
                int wordEnd = j - 1;

                // Выводим слово
                for (int k = wordStart; k <= wordEnd; k++) 
                {
                    cout << sentence[k];
                }
                cout << endl;

                wordCount++;
            }
            i = j - 1;
        }
        else {
            spaceCount++;
        }
    }

    cout << "Количество слов, заканчивающихся на ту же букву, что и первое слово: " << wordCount << endl;

    return 0;
}```
````